# Development desktop/responsive

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is a way to charge 2 diferent templates, 1 for desktop and 1 for movile/responsive.

Like:

```
if ($desktop){

load_template(desktop);

}else{

load_template(movile);

}
```

Comment: It’s not possible to _reliably_ detect whether a device is a mobile device or a “desktop” (whatever that is) from the server. The modern approach is still to control layout across devices client side with CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Someone might try to point to `wp_is_mobile()`, but notice that I said _reliably_. That function only uses a small list of user agents to target a handful of mobile browsers, but it’s an old list that doesn’t reflect the modern diversity of devices

Comment: There is a nice tiny php library for detecting devices. You can use that to setup your conditions https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect